# Micro USB Type B Splitter?

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

Is there a way to connect multiple (around 3-10) devices with a single micro usb-b cable?

Planning to do something similar to this:

[image: open device lab]

With the end result to hopefully have all devices synchronized so that navigating to one site on one device will in turn navigate to that site on all devices.

Also sorry if it's the wrong section of StackExchange or if I've used the incorrect tags :)

Comment: No, that is not how USB works.  And even if there were, it would not result in synchronization.  That would be a software task, and you might as well do it over the network or even with local acoustic signals.  This question will be closed as it is about the *usage* or electronic devices rather than being about *electronic design*.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, thanks for the prompt reply, I'm just looking for a cable that meets my needs, I'm quite aware that my task is a software limitation although your comment is completely unrelated to my question (and quite frankly comes across as quite rude), I thought I made that clear enough in my question that I was looking for the CABLE or atleast a way to have EACH device powered from one cable as the software I use works off remote protocols so data transfer isn't a requirement with the cable.

Comment: USB is point to point only. You cannot daisy-chain USB.

Comment: @Sparky256, And that includes not requiring ANY sort of data transfer?

Comment: @Brandito - on stack exchange sites you get responses to the question you *actually* typed, rather than the one in your head.  If you are going to accuse people of being "rude" for pointing out that the goals mentioned in your question cannot be achieved by the methods mentioned in your question, you will not get far here.  Nor will you get far by posting questions on sites where they *do not belong* to begin with.

Comment: *"And that includes not requiring ANY sort of data transfer?"* But you said you want all devices to navigate on the same website. How do you envision the navigation to a website without any sort of data communication?

Comment: @AliChen chrome has some great built-in remote protocols for that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some other data communication protocol (WiFi, Bluetooth) and don't need USB data transfer, then yes, you take a single 5V@15A DC power supply (if you need 10 devices to feed), and make 10 USB Type micro-B cables, connecting all red wires (VBUS) to +5V, and all black wires (ground) to 0 V. If you also connect all green and white wires together (NOTE1), all your devices will sense Chinese-style (most common) charger signature, and will more or less happily power-up and charge.

NOTE1: you might need to connect green-white wires individually per each forked cable, who knows how your devices determine the D+/D- short, to avoid possible interference.